# Must I download The Windows 10 Upgrade for every PC on my network?

Tags: windows, windows-update, upgrade, windows-10

Windows 10 is out this week!  I want to upgrade all the machines on my network to Windows 10, but not have to download it for each of them.  That would kill my internet connection.

Is there a way that I can download the files once, and use them to run the upgrade?  Are the files specific for each computer?

I have heard that I can download the ISO, but I also have heard that I need to reserve the upgrade from the Windows 7/8 so that it will be license properly.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reserve a copy, you just have to have a qualifying system. If your systems have pre-installed (OEM) or retail boxed Windows 7 or 8, then you can use the [ISO link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) that Michael Hampton provided in his comment.

If you have deployed volume-licensed Windows 7 or 8, then you'll have to download an ISO from the [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx).

As you'll see, there are different ISOs for x86 or x64, and you'll want to install the same architecture the computer has for 7 or 8.

Comment: Note though, that the _same_ ISO can upgrade to either Windows 10 Home or Pro.

Comment: Also note that you can automate the upgrade. If you’re using SCCM, see:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrteam/archive/2015/06/16/revised-content-for-the-win10-in-place-upgrade-via-task-sequence-for-configmgr.aspx